# Passing an array by reference in JavaScript and overriding array

Tags: javascript

In the line I have commented below, does the value of the array that has "element" as a value get overridden by array?

```js
let c = [1, 2];
console.log(`c = ${c}`);
add(c, 3);
console.log(`c = ${c}`);

function add(array, element) {
  array = [element]; // Is this Array that has "element" as a value overridden by array
}
```

Comment: You don't override the array. You change the value that is stored in the local `array` variable. That does not influence the value stored in the global `c` variable.

Comment: What you're describing is a *pass by reference* semantic, and no, JS doesn't have that. You get a copy of a type that is a *reference type*, so that assigning it doesn't copy the whole array, but no, you're not passing a reference to the original variable, so there's no dereferencing on assignment.

Comment: Javascript is pass by value language. In case of objects, value of a variable is a reference. When you pass array `c` to `add` function, you are passing a value of variable `c` which is a reference to an array and this is assigned to local variable `array` of `add` function. But inside the function, you re-assign `array` variable to another array which holds single element. If you call `push` function on the `array`, you will see the changes in the array defined in global scope but re-assigning will not have any affect on the globally defined array.